# How to trigger @LastModifiedDate

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have class with these fields:

```
    private String statusMessage;

    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Instant lastUpdatedAt;
```

What I do is:

- set `statusMessage` field
- save object to repo

Everything is fine, `lastUpdatedAt` is populated with current timestamp.
Problem is that I would like to update `lastUpdatedAt` every time a value is set to `statusMessage`, even when I set the same value as there already is in `statusMessage`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'd rely on the database to mange that, mySQL and mariaDB have this ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP stuff which is pretty neat. Just to add another approach ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the `Spring Data JPA Auditing` features. To achieve that, you just need to add the annotation to a configuration class:

```
@EnableJpaAuditing
```

If you don't, the annotation `@LastModifiedDate` will have no effects in you entity.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I edited my description because it did not reflect the situation as it is. I would like to update `lastUpdatedAt ` every time a value is set to `statusMessage`, even if the value is the same

Comment: So, you will need to force this programmatically. If it worked like this, I would say it's a bug as your entity will not be dirty and it will not be persisted. Anyway, I should recommend you to avoid doing that if possible. Be careful.